# TypeError: Field 'facebook_reactions' expected a number but got <class 'rest_framework.fields.IntegerField'>

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am facing an issue when testing my EventViewSet. I get the following error

```
TypeError: Field 'facebook_reactions' expected a number but got <class 'rest_framework.fields.IntegerField'>.
```

This is the test I ran:

```
class EventViewSetTest(BaseTestCase):
    def test_event_created(self):
        event_data = {
            "url": "www.example.com",
            "tweet_text": "Event successful",
            "facebook_reactions": 2,
        }
        response = self.client.post("/api/events/", event_data)
        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED,response.status_code)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
class EventViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            return serializers.EventCreateSerializer
        return serializers.EventSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        Event.objects.create(
            url=Link.objects.get_or_create(url=serializer.url)[0],
            tweet_text=serializer.tweet_text,
            facebook_reactions=serializer.facebook_reactions,
        )
```

Here is my serializers.py:

```
class EventCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    url = serializers.URLField
    tweet_text = serializers.CharField
    facebook_reactions = serializers.IntegerField


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ["url", "tweet_text", "facebook_reactions"]
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *call* the constructors of the fields, so:

```
class EventCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    url = serializers.URLField()
    tweet_text = serializers.CharField()
    facebook_reactions = serializers.IntegerField()
```

as for the `perform_create`, you need to work with the data`.validated_data`, so:

```
class EventViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # …

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        data = serializer.validated_data
        Event.objects.create(
            url=Link.objects.get_or_create(url=data['url'])[0],
            tweet_text=data['tweet_text'],
            facebook_reactions=data['facebook_reactions'],
        )
```

Comment: I am getting this `AssertionError: 201 != 400` , why do you think that is?

Comment: @NabeelHassan: because the serializer validates the data and the data you submit is not valid. For example the URL needs a protocol. You can print the body of the response to see what the problem is.